# Random blank white window on GLFW app launch (glfwSwapBuffers non-functional)

Tags: opengl, windows-10, glfw

**NOTE: This is not a generic 'Why is my app not drawing anything?'**

It is nothing to do with matrices, or clearing the depth buffer, or setting the scissor area, or vertex buffers, or textures, or glEnabling anything :) I don't need to draw anything or even clear the screen to get this problem to manifest.

It is a very, very specific situation which I've been able to narrow down to the following sequence:

1. glfwInit() succeeds
2. glfwCreateWindow() also succeeds
3. glfwSwapBuffers() **sometimes does nothing for the lifetime of the window**

**Context and Investigation Thus Far:**

Ever since a recent Windows update, our game will randomly, sometimes, launch to a permanently blank white window. No errors, no glfw errors, no gl errors. The app runs, and seemingly renders and updates as normal, but the window remains forever blank white.

*Ok, so what's the difference between a normal and a blank launch?*

I used APITRACE to capture successful and unsuccessful launches. The traces were identical.

I also single-stepped through the window creation and buffer-swapping and everything was above-board and effectively identical (bar the physical memory addresses of the window returned by glfw, etc, which change from launch to launch regardless of the launch being a success or not)

*What did qapitrace do when you replayed the traces?*

Replaying the successful trace through qapitrace usually shows the first few seconds of the app, and sometimes a blank grey window.

Replaying the (identical) 'blank' trace through qapitrace usually shows the first few seconds of the app, and sometimes a blank grey window.

Thus the bug is not part of the trace, or caused by other activities of the app, but manifests in some other way that also randomly afflicts qapitrace.

qapitrace reports no errors.

*When does the bug manifest?*

Very early. In the simplest repro case I init glfw, create a window, show it, and then call glfwSwapBuffers. I don't draw anything or even clear the screen.

*If the window appears black* then that first call to glfwSwapBuffers has worked, and will continue to work throughout the lifetime of the app.

*If the window appears white* then glfwSwapBuffers has **not** worked (though it generates no errors), and will **never** work until I recreate the window or relaunch the app.

(NB: Any window created through glfw seems to have a roughly equal chance of being stuck blank. I've tried destroying and recreating the window twice or more on launch: each window opened will be randomly black (subsequently functional) or white (permanently blank). Since no errors are generated I have no way of knowing whether a window has 'taken' or not, so I can't even keep trying until I get a functional window)

I've narrowed the repro steps down to this:

```
<standard glfwInit>
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RED_BITS,8 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_GREEN_BITS,8 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_BLUE_BITS,8 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_ALPHA_BITS,0 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_DEPTH_BITS,32 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_STENCIL_BITS,0 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE,false );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_DECORATED,true );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_FLOATING,false );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_VISIBLE,false );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER,true );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_SAMPLES,0 );   
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_REFRESH_RATE,60 );

GLFWmonitor *monitor=0;

_window=glfwCreateWindow( width,height,_STRINGIZE(CFG_GLFW_WINDOW_TITLE),monitor,0 );
if( !_window ){
    <report error>
    abort();
}

glfwSetWindowPos( _window,(_desktopMode.width-width)/2,(_desktopMode.height-height)/2 );
glfwShowWindow( _window );
glfwMakeContextCurrent( _window );
glfwSwapInterval( 0 );
glfwSwapBuffers( _window );
```

If the window appears black, then that first 'swapbuffers' at the end worked, and subsequent swapbuffers will also work, allowing the app to display as normal.

If the window appears white (sometimes rarely, sometimes multiple times in a row), then that first 'swapbuffers' has failed, silently, and will never work until the window is recreated.

I'm seeing this on Intel HD Graphics 4600. <del>It also happens on an 880M laptop, and I've getting reports from AMD users as well.</del> AMD reports were for an unrelated blank screen issue. Windows 10 only.

Comment: I remember some sort of this behaviour with Intel HD driver. Not sure, but I think I worked it out by forcing a new framebufer update, say new data/viewport/etc.